# ImageJ saving "anisotropic diffusion 2D" plugin output in a macro

Tags: plugins, macros, imagej

I have been trying to create a macro in ImageJ (Fiji) that would allow me to batch process a stack of images in a folder using the "anisotropic diffusion 2D" plug-in and automatically save outputs of the plug-in into a dedicated folder.
However, while I am managing to run the plug-in from the macro, I am not able to save the new processed image that it generates, it only saves the unprocessed starting image. I am wondering whether I have to somehow select the newly created image before attempting to save the image. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow.com. Why don't you post the macro you already tried, so others can help you using this as a starting point? Also, with questions on ImageJ and macros, you are more likely to get a timely response on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The following macro I recorded using ImageJ's [macro recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder):

```bs
run("Blobs (25K)");
run("Anisotropic Diffusion 2D", "number=20 smoothings=1 keep=20 a1=0.50 a2=0.90 dt=20 edge=5");
saveAs("Tiff", "C:\\temp\\blobs-iter20.tif");
```

and it works as expected, opening the *Blobs* sample image and saving the result image generated by the [Anisotropic Diffusion 2D](http://imagej.net/Anisotropic_Diffusion_2D) plugin in *C:\temp\blobs-iter20.tif*.